# C# .NetCore windows Notification?

Tags: c#, .net-core, notifications, popup

Is there a way to get a Popup Menue or a side-bar Notification from a .NetCore (version 3.1) Programm?

I tried mulitple solutions like MessageBox and ToastNotification but none of them work. MessageBox doesnt let me add "using" (somehow it should be possible but its loading for over an hour and nothing happpens) and ToastNotification just doesnt give me back anything.... like i get no error and no Notification and debugging doesnt tell me any useful values ...

[image]

Comment: Please add what framework are you using - WinForm, WPF or maybe something different.

Comment: Im programming a C# console application with the .NET Core 3.1 framework

Comment: I now got it to work the main problem was that in .NetCore there has to be an XML file first that you have to initialize first. And you also ned the ToastNotifiaction and not the ToeastContentBuilder.

Comment: Nice to hear that you found the solution. Please write an answer with details and mark it as accepted - sure it would be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the ToastContentBuilder somehow doesn't work. I assume the Builder is supposed to create a XML, that is then thrown into the ToastNotification. With .NetCore 3.1 that doesn't work (maybe in some other frameworks it works). So the solution to that problem is to create the XML file by yourself. So here is a function that everyone can use. The only thing that has to be edited so that it work in other codes is at .CreateToast Notifier. There you have to enter the name of your project.

```
 public static void showToastNotification(string toastText)
    {
        XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText01);

        XmlNodeList stringElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");

        for (int i = 0; i < stringElements.Length; i++)
        {
            stringElements[i].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(toastText));
        }

        ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
        toast.Activated += Toast_Activated;
        toast.Dismissed += Toast_Dismissed;
        toast.Failed += Toast_Failed;

        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("'Your project name'").Show(toast);
    }
```